# Can I travel Without Visa to Argentina using UE passport with a different first name on the ticket

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality, argentina

I booked a plane ticket to Argentina with my name as it is on my Tunisian passport.
Recently I changed my first name on my french passport so the first name doesn't match the one for the plane ticket/Tunisian passport.
So my question is can I travel to Argentina using my Tunisian passport as document of identification and my french passport as a visa/proof of right of entry ? Or the airline may refuse it.
Is there any other solution than applying for Argentinian visa with my Tunisian passport ?

Comment: Is the change in your first name significant (eg completely different)? Have you tried asking if the airline will amend your ticket?

Comment: Which airline are you using, where are you transiting, and is it a direct connection on the same ticket, or do you have a stopover or separate tickets? Do you have a document which justifies the name change?

Answer (score -2):

You won't have any problems. Use your Tunisian Passport to buy the ticket and make the check-in. 
On arrival immigration you should show your French passport.

Same process when you leave.

Check-In with Tunisian passport, and exit immigration with French Passport.

Comment: That seems highly unlikely. The airline will ask for proof that the passenger is allowed to enter the destination country. A Tunisian citizen needs a visa to enter Argentina, which OP doesn't have, so showing the Tunisian passport won't be enough. Showing the French passport should be enough, but the name doesn't match...